# How to get the value of a property - 1?

Tags: python, properties, type-conversion

I have a property that is a number. I want to have a variable that is that value minus 1:

```
class temp_conn:
    def __init__(self):
        self._t = 0
    @property
    def t(self):
        return self._t
    @t.setter
    def t(self,value):
        self._t = value

hist = temp_conn.t - 1
```

When I do this it tells me that this is an illegal operand for property and `int`, and I can't convert a property to an `int`. How can I get the equivalent of `temp_conn.t - 1`?

Comment: You name the parameter the same as the underlying field?

Comment: You must create an instance of the class!

Comment: `temp_conn.t` is a `property object` (a Python descriptor) of class `temp_conn`. For it to function it must be called with an **instance** of that class, not the class itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initiate the class first

```
hist = temp_conn().t - 1
```

However, you have other problems. Doing the above code will raise:

`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

You will need change `self.t` becuase it shares a name with the property, i.e. the property will keep calling itself (as shown in the error above).

ex:

```
In [3]: class temp_conn:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self._t = 0
   ...:     @property
   ...:     def t(self):
   ...:         return self._t
   ...:     @t.setter
   ...:     def t(self,value):
   ...:         self._t = value
```

Comment: whats the 'In [3]:'? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @drako234 I was running python in shell